# How to make my texture not get stretched along a face in blender?

Tags: textures, game-engine, blender

I have a school project at hand, and I would like to keep it as simple as possible. The project is an interactive fps game, where you can just walk in my school territory and its buildings (Blender Game render). I have modeled a house floor via box-modeling and each floor is a separate face of my object. When I applied my textures at first I encountered the problem of not seeing any textures when playing. I settled that by going into texture viewport shading. Now I can see textures but they are utterly stretched. I tried applying x-repeat and y-repeat to repeat the texture image on the face but nothing changed.
In the end of the project I may be encountering many other problems, because I have to make it so you can download the game and without installing blender, you should be able to play it in your computer. Is it even possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You said each floor is a face of the same object? If that's the case, then you should be able to simply cover the floor texture with each face simultaneously. Overlapping like that isn't usually a good idea, but if they all look the same it's fine to cheat a little. (Think of each floor as a square, simply place them all on top of each other in the same space, that way you don't need to squish them all in.)

Comment: I addad an image to my description, each face there is either a floor or a place where i will eventually extrude walls from. Maybe i made it clearer, either way thanks for helping.

Comment: In this case, you need a higher resolution texture. You can do that easily by simply copying your smaller texture to fill a larger space. (If it's seamless)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand this, you try to texture the floor only.

1. Select all faces that will have the floor texture
2. Unwrap the selected faces
3. Add a seperate material for the floor, and assign the selected faces to that material by clicking 'Assign'
4. Add a the texture to that material
5. Maybe change the uvmap-size. If you want to have the texture repeated make sure your texture is seamless.

I quickly gone throught these steps and made [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lvaga.png). (6) is the result

I hope I could help you!